# Instagram Access Token Fails after some time

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I made An app (which is Live now and) it Uses Instagram API.

It uses one access token per hour. (which is far away from limit 5000/hour)

But What I see that say if 25 users gave access to me than each day 2 to 4 user's access token become invalid **(seems randomly)**.

But Instagram says that:

> Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration time, your
>   app should handle the case that either the user revokes access, or
>   Instagram expires the token after some period of time. If the token is
>   no longer valid, API responses will contain an
>   “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenException”. In this case you will need to
>   re-authenticate the user to obtain a new valid token. In other words:
>   do not assume your access_token is valid forever.

**I confirmed that none of these "Revoked Access".**

Is there any reason that why its happening.

Or any platform where I can contact Instagram and ask the reason.
So that I can avoid it. (if I 'm doing something wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the tokens have a tendency to (seemingly) randomly expire. I think the reason is that Instagram doesn't want a single token to grant full access to a user's content without expiration.

> Instagram expires the token after some period of time

I would recommend having the user re-auth through Instagram to get a fresh token, as they suggest, and making sure that you are able to handle that OAuth exception when it happens.

> In this case you will need to re-authenticate the user to obtain a new valid token.
>
> do not assume your access_token is valid forever.

Also, since the permissions update on 2016-06-01, Instagram has been somewhat hostile and generally unhelpful toward 3rd party apps, so it's not really worth contacting them.